# $inc not working with $Push in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is My Code

```
db.contests.update(
        { _id: ObjectId("5ad7904d44e6c9330c3aeb6b") },   
        { $push : { players: { $each: [ {teamId:340000474, TeamName : 'xx'}] } } },
        { $inc : { "joinedplayers": 1 } } 
    )
```

In the above mongodb update query, `$push` is working fine and adding the data to the array in the document but `$inc` is not working it doesn't increase the count, the `joinedplayers` filed remains at default `"0"`

There is no Error, Output from Mongodb Shell is this

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

What may be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
db.contests.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5ad7904d44e6c9330c3aeb6b") },   
    { 
        $push : { players: { $each: [ {teamId:340000474, TeamName : 'xx'}] } }, 
        $inc : { "joinedplayers": 1 } 
})
```

Basically both `$push` and `$inc` need to be a part of one object which represents update operation.

Comment: perfect !! ................ thank you, i wonder why mongo shell didn't put up an error or warning, well anyway...!